# How can a route finding program avoid obstacles/locations when calculating routes?

Tags: algorithms

Do you delete nodes from the underlying graph representation? Or is there a more elegant way to do it?

Comment: **Unclear what help you need.** Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell what problem you are trying to solve or what aspect of your approach needs to be corrected or explained. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Questions in the format "How did X solve problem Y" are usually not helpful. 1. When X is not open source, the only one who could know is someone who worked for X. It is unlikely that someone who did reads the question, and when they do they might be bound to a NDA. 2. Just because their solution worked for them doesn't mean that the same solution would be the right thing to do in your special situation.

Comment: I edited the question to remove the mention of a specific product and be more general instead.

Comment: Apologies for not being more general. And I'm not quite sure how I could be more clear as I myself wasn't quite sure what I wanted. But the answer that I accepted below is what I was looking for so if someone wants to edit the question details to reflect, please go ahead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most route finding algorithms allow to assign arbitrary costs to edges (connection between nodes). The algorithm will then not select the *shortest* route (measured in edge-count) but the *least costly* route. In a road navigation application there isn't really a way around that, because large roads should usually be preferred over small roads which means that they would have a lower cost per km.

When you deem a certain road connection temporarily unsuitable (like a traffic jam), you can temporarily add an additional cost to that edge. The route finding algorithm will then not use that road unless there is no reasonable other path. To make it completely impossible to use a road (when it's blocked), you can either assign a cost of *infinity* to it or make the algorithm skip blocked edges altogether.